# How can I update a MVC model list property first be compiling the list on client

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

How can I update a MVC model list property dynamically when a user adds value each time to an input field on a view

My app is a C# web application and I am using razor Views.

So, my Model has a property called workers of data type List:

```
public class Factory
{
    public List<worker> workers { get; set; }

    public class worker
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And, in the Razor View I have the following:

```
@model App.Models. Factory

<div id="worker" class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.workers, new { @class = "col-lg-2 control-label" })
    <div class="container">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.workers, new { placeholder = "worker name", @class="form-control", id="workerinput"})  
    </div>
</div>
```

The input `@Html.TextBoxFor` should have a corresponding button called "Add worker". So, when the user adds a worker and clicks the button, the name of the worker  should be added to the list of workers. The user can add multiple workers.

How can I add each name on the client(say 5 names) then update the model on the server?

Comment: Make an ajax call to add the worker and retrieve the new list of workes. Use jquery to bind the returned JSON result back to the list.

Comment: Would it be easier to store each added worker name to an array of workers? The problem is how do I assign each name in array back to the workers model.

Comment: I do not understand why you want to store it in an array and where is that array? On the client? or Server? You can add the value directly to the List. But If you need to persist the value for future use I think you need to send it back to the server to store it in some sort of database/cache/session.

Comment: Yes. i would like to send the data back to the model to persist. The question I am asking is how to dynamically add each name input one at a time to the model on the client before sending it back to server. I font think its a good design to add/persist/retrieve each time for every individual user added. One user on the client can add multiple names

Comment: I modeified the question. I may have asked the question wrongly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a sample, you might need to modify the code a bit.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var workers = new Array();
    function addWorker() {
        workers.push($("#TextToAdd").val());
    }

    function submit() {
        var postData = { names: workers };
        $.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("AddWorker", "Home")',
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: postData,
            success: function () {
                alert("Added");
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Here are the controls

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.TextToAdd)
@Html.DropDownList("workerList", items);
<input type="button" value="addlocal" onclick="addWorker();" />
<input type="button" value="Post" onclick="submit();" />
```

And in the controller you need to add all items back to the list. Hope this helps.

```
    public ActionResult AddWorker(List<string> names)
    {

        List<String> strings = new List<string>();
        if (Session["List"] != null)
        {
            strings = (List<String>)Session["List"];
        }
        foreach (var s in names)
        {
            strings.Add(s);
        }

        Session["List"] = strings;
        return Json(strings);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want is to asynchronously post the new item back to the server, and refresh the model. Here is a great example of how to do exactly that:

http://blog.krisvandermast.com/UsingJQueryAjaxToLoadAPartialViewInASPNETMVC2AndThenRetrieveTheInputOnTheServerAgain.aspx

In short, when the user clicks "Add Worker", the view posts the new worker to the server, which then retrieves the full list of workers to return to the view. The view can then be updated to show the full list of workers.

Comment: This is one way of doing it. Ideally I do not want to post each name until the user adds the full list . Say 5 names. I could Store them in a array using jquery/javascript.What I dont know is how to assign an array on the client back to the model on the client before sending to the server. This would avoid 5 hits to the server and just do one post .

Comment: Does this make any sense or am I over thinking the process?